# Looking to create a filter based on a rating/score for archiving purposes

Tags: google-sheets

I've messed around in the custom formula and using what I've dug up on youtube and stackoverflow to no avail. I'm trying to archive reviews for a site and am making a filter. The filter will be based on score/ratings where "Read it Now" is the best (a 4), "Crackers" is really good (a 3), "Read it at Barnes" is ok (a 2), and "Burn it" is the worst rating (a 1).
I've tried doing filters and making the formula custom like this
=FILTER(A3:D999, C3:C="Read", C3:C="Crackers", C3:C="Barnes", C3:C="Burn")
But no luck. Looking for any and all help to set this up. Please and thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you please share a sample sheet? Or at least a clear example of input and deisred output? Do you want to give a numeric rating based on the characters o vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

This simple lik e an easy to achieve task. And of course there are multiple ways that you can make it work but I will suggest the use of `SWITCH`

#### Function

```
=SWITCH(B1:B6,"Read it Now", 4, "Crackers", 3, "Read it at Barnes", 2, "Burn it", 1)
```

Of course instead of using the range `B1:B6` use the range of the column that you want to address.

#### Example

[image: Sample of use]

Comment: That seems to require an extra column. I'm looking to use the "Create a filter" feature and have it able to sort from highest rating to lowest rating without making an extra sheet or column if possible.

Comment: What you ask seems to be impossible, is adding that extra column too troublesome? Maybe if you want it to get sort an Apps Script could do the trick but that would actually change all the list, not like a filter.

Comment: I'm not against using an extra column if it's not possible to make a filter. What do you have in mind?

Comment: The problem about doing stuff with Apps Script is that without creating a filter you would need to change the order of the data introduced or having it presented in another sheet. Sincerely adding an extra column could be "safer" in the terms of not manipulating the already introduced data.

Comment: Let's test it with an extra column then. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Looks like what Rasherin has already done uses the extra column, hence the column of numbers @Broly103091